# Read protobuf message in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, protocol-buffers

I have access to the `python` classes generated through `protoc` for the corresponding messages types.

While trying to read this in Spark(`Kafka -> Structured Streaming`) i found the function `from_protobuf`, however this requires the `descFilePath` which i don't have, or `binaryDescriptorSet` which i am not being able to get from the class. Is this second approach even possible given what i have? Below is what i tried

```
decoded_df = encoded_df.select(
    from_protobuf(
        encoded_df.value,
        messageName=Message().DESCRIPTOR.name,
        binaryDescriptorSet=bytearray.fromhex(
            str(Message().DESCRIPTOR.file.serialized_pb)
        ),
    ))
```

If this doesn't work, i will probably just create an `udf` to convert the message from `protobuf` into a Spark `struct`.

I found `pbspark` but it's not compatible with the requirements i have in my project